# POST dosn't work in yii2 restful API

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I used yii2 restful API  explained hear:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

and in CURL it works correctly for GET and DELETE.
but when i use this in CURL:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
-XPOST "my localhost path/customers"
-d '{"name": "xxxx", "family": "xxxx","mobile":"xxxxx","home":"xxxxx","work":"xxxx"}'
```

It inserts only auto increment field "id", in my table 'customer' and other fields in my database is empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is related to the API functionality but fairly sure this is a "safe attribute" problem in your model.

Please take a look at [this piece of documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#safe-attributes) to make sure that you have marked all those other attributes as safe. Even via a REST call this is still a mass assignment, subject to the same rules.

Basically you either add them in your validation rules as `safe` (at the minimum) or have them returned as part of the `safeAttributes()`-result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
I add the following code in my model class "Customer" and it works:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
    [['name', 'family', 'mobile', 'home', 'work'], 'required'],
    [['name', 'family'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
    [['mobile', 'home', 'work'], 'string', 'max' => 11]
    ];
}
```